# 404 Not Found - can't access login page after upgrade to ownCloud 9

Tags: server, upgrade, apache2, php

I have tried both the package manager upgrade and a manual upgrade to move to the latest ownCloud version (9).  Both methods end up with the same result; the page `http://localhost/owncloud` no longer shows the login page.  Instead, I get a `404 Not Found` error page.  It complains:

> The requested URL /var/www/owncloud/index.php was not found on this server.

but this file still exists, as shown here:

```
$ ll /var/www/owncloud/index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 2026 March  8 08:54 /var/www/owncloud/index.php
```

That, I do not understand but I will admit I know very little about php.

If I restore my whole system from a backup, ownCloud 8 works fine again.  I tried a manual upgrade (again) from this state, and the result is the same.

For completeness, here are the steps I used in my manual upgrade:

```
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/owncloud/occ maintenance:mode --on

tar xjf owncloud-9.0.0.tar.bz2

sudo service apache2 stop

sudo mv /var/www/owncloud /var/www/owncloud-old

sudo cp -avr owncloud /var/www

sudo cp backups/config.php /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php

sudo service apache2 start

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/owncloud

sudo -u www-data /var/www/owncloud/occ upgrade

sudo -u www-data php /var/www/owncloud/occ maintenance:mode --off
```

apache2's `error.log` does not show a problem.  It could be a configuration issue but I do not possess the expertise to understand why OC 8 and OC 9 would behave differently.  `owncloud.conf` is:

```
Alias /owncloud "/var/www/owncloud/"

<Directory "/var/www/owncloud">
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HOME /var/www/owncloud
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/owncloud


</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/owncloud/data/">
  # just in case if .htaccess gets disabled
  Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Based on fkraiem's comments, how can I make sure/know that my server is not looking for `/var/www/var/www/owncloud/index.php` ?  **EDIT:** After doing the following in a virtual machine, the problem persists which probably rules this out:

```
cd /var/www
sudo mkdir var
sudo mkdir var/www
sudo cp -avr owncloud var/www
```

/edit

Is this a php issue, after all?  How do I start troubleshooting based on the symptoms of apache saying that a file cannot be found, but exists?

Comment: Does the error message really include the full path (with `/var/www`)? It does not do that on [my server](http://www.fkraiem.org/notfound.php)...

Comment: Yes, it does.  Maybe it should not?  Will update the post with my owncloud.conf.

Comment: I'm not sure, but since on mine it does not show it, it makes me think maybe your server is looking for  `/var/www/var/www/owncloud/index.php` for some reason...

Comment: By the way, is `owncloud.conf` enabled (*i.e.*, is it in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`)? If it isn't, the `Alias` directive is not applied, which may cause your problem.

Comment: Yes it appears in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` by way of a link, interesting comment about `Alias` though.  I reproduce the whole problem perfect on  Windows-hosted VMWare execution of Ubuntu 15.10, and a fresh install of ownCloud 9.

Comment: I also run ownCloud by the way, but I run it in a [separate domain](https://owncloud.fkraiem.org/) so I don't have this aliasing problem. No problem when upgrading from 8 to 9 either...

Answer (score 4):

There is a tracker for this issue at https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/22970 .

The workaround for the moment is editing the file `/var/www/owncloud/.htaccess` and commenting out the line

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT,E=PATH_INFO:$1]
```

like so

```
# RewriteRule .* index.php [PT,E=PATH_INFO:$1]
```

Save and from the command line do `sudo service apache2 restart`.

I would appreciate anyone's time explaining to me what that line is meant to do.